# Подсчёт количества едениц в строке

Tags: python

Сколько единиц содержится в двоичной записи значения выражения: 4^255 + 2^255 − 255?

```
a = list(bin(4**255+ 2**255 - 255))
k = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 1:
        k += 1
print (k)
```

Что не так? И пожалуйста объясните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Способ 1.**

```
str(4**255 + 2**255 - 255).count('1')
```

Приводим к строке, вызываем строковый метод подсчета символа.

**Способ 2.**

```
sum(1 for elem in bin(4**255+ 2**255 - 255)) if elem == '1')
```

Считаем количество единиц, так как функция bin переводит к строковому типу вида **'0bxxx'**, где **xxx** - цифры числа в двоичном представлении.

**Способ 3.**

Также существует несложный алгоритм.

`4^255 = 2^(255 * 2)` степень двойки, будет обозначать единица в двоичном представлении данной суммы.

`2^255` -- аналогично.

С вычитанием интереснее, можно проследить следующую закономерность:

`2^n - 2^m` -- будет содержать `n - m` единиц (проверьте это и докажите самостоятельно).

Отсюда сделаем следующий финт: `-255 = -256 + 1 = -2^8 + 2^0`

В итоге наше выражение: `2^(255 * 2) + 2^255 - 2^8 + 1` будет иметь `1 + (255 - 8) + 1` единицу, так как `2^255 - 2^8` четное число и значит нулевой бит у него будет нулевой и прибавление единицы добавит только единицу.

Comment: Конкретно в вашем случае проблема, что вы проходитесь по элементам строки и символы у нее строчные,а  сравниваете с числом, чтобы все заработало, нужно сравнивать с '1'.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ((8**1341)-(4**1342)+(2**1343)-1344)
result = bin(a).count ('1')
print (result)
```

у меня другое выражение но способ этот тоже работает вроде бы